# Is there any way to merge these three sql statement into single sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select b.b_id from btable b inner join atable a on b.b_id = a_id
go
delete from btable where b_id in (...)
go
insert into btable select * from atable where a_id in (...)
go
```

The second and the third sql statement's conditions are the first sql query result,

now I want to merge these three sql statement into single sql statement,

is there any way?

Comment: @eggyal you mean the "go" statement separator? It is all about my database management client which uses go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do.

PS: having all the 3 clauses in one statement barely would be called "query optimization". Optimization is when you improve a query performance, not when you just take N queries and get them in a single query.

Actually it's a common misunderstanding among newbies - that the less queries automagically means they would perform faster. It's just wrong. You should have as many queries as you need to retrieve all the necessary data - not less and not more.

Comment: Is it possible the OP is asking for a transactional query?

Comment: @Adrian Cornish: I see `query-optimization` tag

Comment: Could be - gut feeling they want to combine them in a transaction - who knows though :-)

Comment: It was my mistake for using `query-optimization` tag, I focus on combining these sql statements.

Comment: @KindleBaby: combine to what? With what reason?

Comment: @zerkms merge(combine) three sql statements into single one. because i have many 'three sql statements' and it would be clearly for using 'single statement'

Comment: @KindleBaby: There is nothing wrong with 3 queries. And as I said - less query doesn't mean better

Answer (score 2):

The question would be why - if they all must be performed in a sequence then you could group them as a transaction if they are related - but that would depend on you table engines

This would require that all three worked if they are a transaction.

Also in a transaction you can test the result of a sql command and decided if you want/need to continue it

Comment: "Also in a transaction you can test the result of a sql command and decided if you want/need to continue it" --- I've never seen that in my practice. The result of execution of sql command is strictly determined. You can know it on the programming step, so no reason to do that in runtime.

Comment: @zerkms You should be able to determine the result is a SP. But I agree harder when issuing individual commands at prompt

Comment: the reason is quite simple: I have many 'three sql statements' and it would be clear for using 'single statement'.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that, merging will  not be possible but what you can do is that put the initial result set into a temp table and reuse it.

Like

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl (b_id int)

select b.b_id into tbl from btable b inner join atable a on b.b_id = a_id

delete from btable where b_id in (select b_id from tbl)

insert into btable select * from atable where a_id in (select b_id from tbl)

drop table tbl
```

I hope that this will give you some idea to start.